# Why does Excel crash when attempting to update a pivot table connection?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, data-connections

I have a pivot table attached to  a table of 65 rows of data, 8 columns.  I have added a slicer of 1 of the columns.  When I attempt to update the pivot table connections to have the slicer control others Excel crashes.  I am unable to add other charts to the slicer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
TM

Comment: Are there any `Workbook_Change` events in your file, and do any formulas pull from your pivot table?

Comment: No all the VBA code is commented out currently

Comment: There is a calculated field in the pivot table.  Does that matter?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could try removing it and then updating again and see if that makes any difference.